# how to know why WCF service stopped

Tags: c#, wcf, service

We have developed WCF service and hosted as windows service. We have written .net core client application.
We have observed that the service is not responding after a few calls. It gets stopped somehow.
I tried to create logging and trace in WCF service but it is not creating any .svclog file.

In exception handling, it gives the following message

> Exception: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while
> sending the request.) System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An
> error occurred while sending the request.  --->
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request.  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
> transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
> the remote host..  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An
> existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    --- End
> of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16
> token)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I want to know what forced the service to be stopped? How can I find this?

Comment: You are out of luck. You need to debug on the server side.

Comment: An exception is thrown in the OnStart method when your service is stopped immediately. Use `try-catch` to catch exceptions. You need to check if the application is running as administrator, this issue may also be related to transport level security, try adding the following line.`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`